# append a method inside a list in JAVA

Tags: java, list, methods, append

i am a begginer with Java but i want to ask if i can append a method inside a list and how can i make a list? here is my code

```
public class My_Zoo {

    private String Animal_name;
    private String Cohabitation;
    private String Gender;
    private int Weight;
    private int Maximum_age;
    private String Animal_code;

    public void Get_Animal(String A_name, String C, String G , int W , int M_a, String A_c ){
        Animal_name = A_name;
        Cohabitation = C;
        Gender = G;
        Weight = W;
        Maximum_age = M_a;
        Animal_code = A_c;
    }

    public void Tiger(){

        Animal_name = "Tiger";
        Cohabitation = "mammal";
        Gender = "Female";
        Weight = 170;
        Maximum_age = 15;
        Animal_code = "A01";

    }

}
```

Comment: What method and what list?

Comment: I mean, in general sure, you can. The question is why?

Comment: public void Tiger(){} isn't a method?

Comment: what's the deffrence between a method and a constructor? I'm sorry i'm a little confused...I wanted to make some methods and add them in a list but i don't know how

Comment: Please first answer this: why do you want to do that? I'm asking because maybe we're not speaking about the same thing, and knowing what you're trying to do can help understand.

Comment: Sorry, I further confused you saying that was a constructor. It wasn't, it was a method. But I still don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Look i have a project for my university and the project wants the user to choose a number from the menu: 1. View all available zoo animals.... i made the input and i made another file that contains variables . I made the variables to be private and thats why i made mathods to give them values but i want the methods to add them in a list and when the user write the number 1 from the menu, i want to appear all the elements of my list (in other words the methods)

Comment: i hope you understand now , sorry i don't speak very well english , i'm foreign.

Answer (score 1):

As you are starting with Java I think there are some things that we might say.

## Java Conventions

In Java the name of everything has a convention, you can find it here:[code conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Let me say some that might help you:

1. Class names: you do not use undescore, you will allways use CamelCase with first letter in capital, for exemple insteade of My_Zoo you should use MyZoo
2. Variable and parameters name: same as above, but withou first letter in capital, instead of Animal_name you should use animalName

## Constructors

I noticed that you tried to make 2 constructors, Get_Animal and Tiger. In java all constructors have the same name of the class. If you do not put any constructors inside a class Java will use the default constructor that looks like this.

```
public MyZoo(){}
```

The only difference allowed between constructors is it´s parameters, so you cannot create it with different names, but you can make static methods that create objects for you:

```
    public static MyZoo Tiger(){
       MyZoo tiger = new MyZoo();//create the object
       //use this to set the fields you you want
       return tiger; //return the desired object
    }
```

You can make the methods getAnimal and Tiger to be this way.

More information about static methods: [static methods](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-methods-vs-instance-methods-java/)

## Lists

In Java we have a class called Collections, on java.util package. All forms of collections extends from it, including the List class.

Those classes has methods to abstracts arrays and matrices processes. More about it: [Collections](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-in-java-2/)

As it means only to hold a set of values your question doesn´t make sense, it seems that you are asking how to put a method inside a class. To me it appears you are mistaking list with class concept.

Although with java 8 or +, you can use the functional interface an make use of the function as a high order cientizen concept and add methods to a list, that must be a list of methods from the begning, as you are starting in Java and it is a advanced concept I don´t think it is your doubt.

## Methods

At least let´s go to your question, but you already made it. Methods in java has 3 basic components: access modifier, return type and a name. You made 2: Get_Animal and Tiger. In Java syntax they are methods, not constructors as I said earlier. If you want put more methods just follow these rules, it´s pretty simple: [Java Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods.asp)

I hope that things got more clear for you.

And you should learn more about Object Oriented concepts as weel, for example [encapisulation](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_encapsulation.asp), so you can access your fields from outside this class, you noted them with private modifier, so outside your class no one can see them.

Comment: Anything, just ask